# Import variables from another file

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a script file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

. /home/$USER/git_projects/cfhookbash/config.txt

deploy_challenge() {
}
```

In config.txt there is `www.example.com_token="asdfasdf"`

I need to print (or reuse) the value of `www.example.com_token`, in my example `asdfasdf`.

I get `/home/sineverba/git_projects/cfhookbash/config.txt: line 1: www.k2p.it_token=asdfasdf: command not found`

Comment: That's not a valid shell variable name. In the manual, look at [Shell Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters) and then look up `name` in [Definitions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Definitions)

Answer (score 6):

In `bash`, variable names can only be made of single-byte alphanumeric characters or underscore (and the first character cannot be a digit).

So, `www.example.com_token` being not a valid variable name,  `www.example.com_token="asdfasdf"` is not recognised as an assignment but as a simple command.

In ksh93 (the shell `bash` tries to emulate), `www.example.com_token="asdfasdf"` would work only if you defined the `www` variable as a *compound* variable:

```
$ compound www
$ www.example.com_token="asdfasdf"
$ typeset -p www
typeset -C www=(example=(com_token=asdfasdf))
$ printf '%s\n' "${www.example.com_token}"
asdfasdf
```

In `bash`, you could possibly use an associative array variable (one of those ksh93 features copied by `bash`):

```
typeset -A token
token[www.example.com]=asdfasdf
printf '%s\n' "${token[www.example.com]}"
```

(that syntax should also work in `ksh93` and `zsh`).

If you can't  modify that  `config.txt` so it's compatible with your shell's syntax, you could possibly edit it on the fly before evaluating. Like (with `ksh93`, `bash` or `zsh`):

```
typeset -A token
. <(sed 's/^\([^=]*\)_token=/token[\1]=/' < config.txt)
```

To transform the `x.y_token=` to `token[x.y]=` or:

```
. <(sed -e :1 -e 's/^\([^=]*\)\.\(.*=\)/\1_\2/; t1' < config.txt)
```

To replace every `.` left of the `=` with `_`.

But beware any of those could do replacements in places where they are not expected like in:

```
foo.bar_token="multi
line .x. _token assignment (=)"
```

Or if the file does not contain only assignments.

Now, if that `config.txt` is actually not containing proper shell syntax, you want to look out for other syntax issues like lines containing `foo="price: $12"` or `` foo="x `y' z" `` where those `$`, `` ` `` are special operators in the shell syntax.

Answer (score 2):

As I commented, you can't just source that txt file, because it's not a valid shell script.

To get that *particular* value, try

```
config=/home/$USER/git_projects/cfhookbash/config.txt
token=$( grep -oP 'www.example.com_token="\K[^"]+' "$config" )
```